# Bind a database connection to QSqlQuery object

Tags: c++, qt

Here's the constructor for `QSqlQuery`:

```
QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery ( QSqlDatabase db )
Constructs a QSqlQuery object using the database db. If db is invalid, 
the application's default database will be used.
```

Is it possible to bind the database connection `QSqlDatabase db` later to the `QSqlQuery`, like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.setDatabase(db);//QSqlQuery does not have a setDatabase method
```

Instead of:

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such option in the API. But the code you've posted can be rewritten like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query = QSqlQuery(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly stated in [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquery.html)

Comment: What I mean is that if it's not in the documentation, you can't do it. The only way I can think of is the way Riateche suggested but then you might as well have a local QSqlQuery whenever you need it. This all makes sense though since there's no point having a query object without a database connection.